# Can I use ModelSerializer (DRF) to move multiple fields to a JSON field in a CREATE method?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm building an API with the Django Rest Framework. The main requirement is that it should allow for the flexible inclusion of extra fields in the call. Based on a POST call, I would like to create a new record in Django, where some fields (varying in name and number) should be added to a JSON field (`lead_request`).

I doubt if I should use the `ModelSerializer`, as I don't know how to handle the various fields that should be merged into one field as a JSON. In the create method, I can't merge the additional fields into the JSON, as they aren't validated.

```py
class Leads(models.Model):
    campaign_id = models.ForeignKey(Campaigns, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    lead_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    lead_request = JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)

class LeadCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_lead_request(self):
        return {key: value for key, value in self.request.items() if key.startswith('rq_')}

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['campaign_id',
                    'lead_email',
                    'lead_request']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Leads.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The documentation mostly talks about assigning `validated_data`, but here that isn't possible.

Comment: can you please include your model defination in this post too. So that it will be helpful to understand the model structure and also this will help people to generate answer.

Comment: the rest framework already handles validation/creation of `JSONField`s: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield
so if you have it on your model and you're using a modelserializer, you should be good to go - by adding the jsonfield_name and then passing a json to it on your `body`. something like: `{ "lead_request": {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"} }`

Comment: @Shakil I've added the model, thanks for looking into this

Comment: @henriquesalvaro Good point and indeed this in theory could be a solution, but not in my use case. The API will be used by other programmers as well and this will then likely be something that they aren't able to do without a lot of support. Also, I want to allow for passing the variables in a link as a parameter and that most probably will not work, passing a JSON as a parameter. Thanks for helping!

Comment: in that case (specially given you want to receive query params), I think you're better off processing the data before passing it to serializer. you can manipulate the `request.data` and the `query_params` on your viewset, you could even do all that and generate the equivalent `json` form of `lead_request` and then pass it processed to your already existing serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to receive parameters through the URL as well, here's an example of how you could achieve what you want:

```
class LeadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      data = request.data
      lead_request = generate_lead_request(request)
      data['lead_request'] = lead_request
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      ...
```

And on `generate_lead_request` you could parse all the additional fields that may have been sent through `request.data` (body) as well as through the `request.query_params`.

Comment: thanks! Looks indeed like this is sort of what I need. Still testing it and will get back to you asap. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: This worked very fine, when setting it up. I also think it is good to convert the variables to the json before passing them to the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem properly main obstruction here is we don't know the exact `JSON` data format of `lead_request`. I am thinking about two possible model of solution for this problem. I not sure either of them is appropriate or not. Just want to share my opinion.

#### case 1

Lets assume data passed to `LeadCreateSerializer` in this type of format

```
data = {

    'campaign_id': campaign_id,
    'lead_email': lead_email,
    'lead_request': { 
         # lead_request
     }

}
```

Then this is easy, normal model serializer should able to do that. If data is not in properly formatted and it possible to organize before passing to serializer that this should those view or functions responsibility to make it proper format.

#### case 2

Lets assume this is not possible to organize data before passing that in `LeadCreateSerializer` then we need to get our related value during the validation or get of lead_request. As this `serializer` responsibility is to create new instance and for that validate fields so we assume in `self.context` the whole `self.context.request` is present.

```
class LeadCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def generate_lead_request(self, data):
         # do your all possible validation and return 
         # in dict format

    def get_lead_request(self):
        request = self.context.request
        lead_request = self.generate_lead_request(request.data)
        return lead_request

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['campaign_id',
                  'lead_email',
                  'lead_request']
```

Comment: Much appreciated and it looks like case 2 is indeed what I'm looking for. Still testing some stuff, to see if this solves it and I'll get back to your later with the final answer!